# OnScroll Event not firing inside a mat-drawer-container

Tags: angular, angular-material2, onscroll

I have a bunch of content inside of a mat-drawer-container and I would like to listen for scroll events on it. I have tried `window.onscroll()` and it did not work. I removed the mat-drawer-container and `window.onscroll()` worked. I think the mat-drawer-container is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you listen to the scroll event on the `mat-drawer-content` class.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mat-drawer-content').item(0)!.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('It works!')
  })
```